# Ionic4-Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic4, capacitor

I cant get data from api with my localhost these are errors.

```
> E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(264)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS   

> E/Capacitor: Post message error:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.privateInitialize(java.lang.String, org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface, org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView, org.apache.cordova.CordovaPreferences)' on a null object reference
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:171)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:122)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.callCordovaPluginMethod(MessageHandler.java:73)
        at com.getcapacitor.MessageHandler.postMessage(MessageHandler.java:46)
        at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
        at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:41)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 

> E/Capacitor/Plugin/Console: ERROR {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://kurutravel/flight/airports","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://kurutravel/flight/airports: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

Comment: Altough you use Angular, your error isn't related to it, so I removed the tag. And welcome to SOF, please read [ask] before submitting a question (maybe uou could provide some more context/insight on your issue by providing more information, like som code for instance ? )

Comment: It is working in browser but I need to use InAppBrowser in my project that is why I need android studio emulator. Thanks for your help @Maryannah

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Which code ? Sorry I am new here, I can't understand easly. @AjayKulkarni

Comment: Your ionic code... I want to see where that `null pointer exception` is happening

Answer (score 0):

I change '''http://hocalhost'''  to '''http://192.168.8.106/''' in config/urls file and it works